# How to mention inserted table in subselect postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to insert some data in new column:

```
insert into orders (delivery_address) 
select address 
from addresses 
where addresses.id = orders.address_id;
```

I found that i cannot mention inserted table 'orders' in subquery.
Is there a way to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: To insert data into a column of the existing row you should use the UPDATE command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `EXISTS` subquery with your condition.

```
insert into orders (delivery_address) 
SELECT address 
FROM addresses t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM orders o
    WHERE t1.id = o.address_id
)
```

Comment: Sorry. don't get it...

Comment: if there is a corresponding id EXISTS return true and adds it into orders

Comment: @IvanKarotki What do you mean don't get it ? could you provide some sample  data and expect result?